# Python pandas 1.3.5 to 1.4.0 breaking changes - Got array instead of string

Tags: python, pandas

I'm encountering an error with the update of pandas version from 1.3.5 to the major version 1.4.0. It is still happening on all subversion 1.4.2 and 1.4.4.

Here is my code:

```
    print(df.T.to_dict().values())
    df = df.reset_index().groupby(['startTime']).agg({
        'startTime': np.unique,
        'endTimes': lambda field: list(field),
        'durationSplit': lambda field: list(field),
        'split': lambda field: list(field),
    })
    print(df.T.to_dict().values())
```

With version 1.35. it print:

```
dict_values([{'startTime': '1970-01-01T10:30:00', 'endTimes': '1970-01-01T13:00:00', 'durationSplit': None, 'split': None}])
dict_values([{'startTime': '1970-01-01T10:30:00', 'endTimes': ['1970-01-01T13:00:00'], 'durationSplit': [None], 'split': [None]}])
```

With versions 1.4.0, 1.4.2, 1.4.4 (1.5.0 too) it print:

```
dict_values([{'startTime': '1970-01-01T10:30:00', 'endTimes': '1970-01-01T13:00:00', 'durationSplit': None, 'split': None}])
dict_values([{'startTime': array(['1970-01-01T10:30:00'], dtype=object), 'endTimes': ['1970-01-01T13:00:00'], 'durationSplit': [None], 'split': [None]}])
```

I cannot find any breaking change about that with pandas or found someone else with the same problem.

I only get a new warning here which say:

```
FutureWarning: Dropping invalid columns in SeriesGroupBy.agg is deprecated. In a future version, a TypeError will be raised. Before calling .agg, select only columns which should be valid for the function.
```

Do you have more information or can explain me what is going on ?
or how can I do something similar differently :')

Thank you by advance for your help !

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to write this aggregation which will work in both versions of Pandas. Specifically, you could write this:

```
df = df.reset_index().groupby(['startTime']).agg({
    'startTime': 'first',
    ...
})
```

Since `startTime` is part of your group key, taking the first element of your group is the same as taking all unique elements. It also won't result in an array.

Bisecting the pandas git repository, I find the commit which first has this behavior is [ad0baebc2a7015a7cf80d39c5b5b21dd8e8bbba6](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/commit/ad0baebc2a7015a7cf80d39c5b5b21dd8e8bbba6), part of PR [#44122](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/44122). Since it's marked as a refactoring, it probably wasn't an intended change.